# Replacing multiple rows with polars , based on filter condition /equivalent to df.loc of pandas

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

consider this dummy dataset,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(25)
num_rows = 6
data = {
    'item_id': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], num_rows),
    'store_id': np.random.choice([1, 2], num_rows),
    'sold_quantity': np.random.randint(0, 5, num_rows),  
    'total_sku_count': np.random.choice([0, 1], num_rows),
    'netsales': np.random.choice([50,100], num_rows)
    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Main dataframe,

```
item_id store_id    sold_quantity   total_sku_count netsales
0   A   2   4   0   100
1   A   2   4   1   50
2   A   1   1   1   100
3   B   1   4   0   50
4   B   2   1   1   100
5   A   1   3   1   100
```

Now i'm creating a filtered df, with rows containing only "item_id"= "A" using ".iloc".Then, i'll change 'netsales' value to 120 for all rows,

```
sub_df = df.loc[df["item_id"]=="A"] 
sub_df['netsales'] = 120
```

This is the filtered df with changed value,

```
    item_id store_id    sold_quantity   total_sku_count netsales
0   A   2   4   0   120
1   A   2   4   1   120
2   A   1   1   1   120
5   A   1   3   1   120
```

Now i can replace the rows of main df ,with filtered df using below line of code on same location.

```
df.loc[df["item_id"]=="A"] = sub_df
```

This is the final df,

```
item_id store_id    sold_quantity   total_sku_count netsales
0   A   2   4   0   120
1   A   2   4   1   120
2   A   1   1   1   120
3   B   1   4   0   50
4   B   2   1   1   100
5   A   1   3   1   120
```

I actually wanted to perform the same operation in Polars. I've attempted to implement this using the 'filter' method of Polars, but I was unsuccessful due to my inexperience with the polars.Please help me if there is a way to achieve this.Your support is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways that you can accomplish your task. IIUC there might be
two questions here:

1. How do you perform the specific action you want.
2. How do we seemingly update a DataFrame

### 1. Replace values in a single column based on condition

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

np.random.seed(25)
num_rows = 6
data = {
    'item_id': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], num_rows),
    'store_id': np.random.choice([1, 2], num_rows),
    'sold_quantity': np.random.randint(0, 5, num_rows),
    'total_sku_count': np.random.choice([0, 1], num_rows),
    'netsales': np.random.choice([50,100], num_rows)

}
pl_df = pl.DataFrame(data).lazy() # We'll use a LazyFrame

pl_df = pl_df.with_columns(
    netsales=pl.when(pl.col('item_id') == 'A').then(120).otherwise(pl.col('netsales'))
)

print(pl_df.collect())
# shape: (6, 5)
# ┌─────────┬──────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────┐
# │ item_id ┆ store_id ┆ sold_quantity ┆ total_sku_count ┆ netsales │
# │ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---           ┆ ---             ┆ ---      │
# │ str     ┆ i64      ┆ i64           ┆ i64             ┆ i64      │
# ╞═════════╪══════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╪══════════╡
# │ A       ┆ 2        ┆ 4             ┆ 0               ┆ 120      │
# │ A       ┆ 2        ┆ 4             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# │ A       ┆ 1        ┆ 1             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# │ B       ┆ 1        ┆ 4             ┆ 0               ┆ 50       │
# │ B       ┆ 2        ┆ 1             ┆ 1               ┆ 100      │
# │ A       ┆ 1        ┆ 3             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# └─────────┴──────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────┘
```

The above complets your operation, however you might also be interested in changing
many columns above in accordance with a subframe.

### 2. "Replacing" a subframe: filter, update

You can partition your DataFrame based on your computed mask, where the in-group
is `df.filter(mask)` and the remaining group would be `df.filter(~mask)`. This
way you can make changes to the in-group and the concatenate the two parts back
together. We’ll also need to track the row numbers to restore the original ordering
of our rows.

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

np.random.seed(25)
num_rows = 6
data = {
    'item_id': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], num_rows),
    'store_id': np.random.choice([1, 2], num_rows),
    'sold_quantity': np.random.randint(0, 5, num_rows),
    'total_sku_count': np.random.choice([0, 1], num_rows),
    'netsales': np.random.choice([50,100], num_rows)

}
pl_df = pl.DataFrame(data).lazy().with_row_count()

mask = pl.col('item_id') == 'A'
sub_df = (
    pl_df.filter(mask)
    .with_columns(netsales=pl.lit(120))
    .cast(pl_df.schema)
)
remaining_df = pl_df.filter(~mask)

# Reconstitute original DataFrame with new chunk
pl_df = pl.concat([remaining_df, sub_df]).sort(pl.col('row_nr'))

print(
    pl_df.collect(),
)
# shape: (6, 6)
# ┌────────┬─────────┬──────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────┐
# │ row_nr ┆ item_id ┆ store_id ┆ sold_quantity ┆ total_sku_count ┆ netsales │
# │ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---           ┆ ---             ┆ ---      │
# │ u32    ┆ str     ┆ i64      ┆ i64           ┆ i64             ┆ i64      │
# ╞════════╪═════════╪══════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╪══════════╡
# │ 0      ┆ A       ┆ 2        ┆ 4             ┆ 0               ┆ 120      │
# │ 1      ┆ A       ┆ 2        ┆ 4             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# │ 2      ┆ A       ┆ 1        ┆ 1             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# │ 3      ┆ B       ┆ 1        ┆ 4             ┆ 0               ┆ 50       │
# │ 4      ┆ B       ┆ 2        ┆ 1             ┆ 1               ┆ 100      │
# │ 5      ┆ A       ┆ 1        ┆ 3             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# └────────┴─────────┴──────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────┘
```

### 3. "Replacing" a subframe: filter, update

Polars also has a `DataFrame.update` method which is used to mimic an in-place update.
This takes a similar approach as we did above, except it utilizes a
`.join(…)….coalesce(…)` under the hood instead of concat.

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

np.random.seed(25)
num_rows = 6
data = {
    'item_id': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], num_rows),
    'store_id': np.random.choice([1, 2], num_rows),
    'sold_quantity': np.random.randint(0, 5, num_rows),
    'total_sku_count': np.random.choice([0, 1], num_rows),
    'netsales': np.random.choice([50,100], num_rows)

}
pl_df = pl.DataFrame(data).lazy().with_row_count()

sub_df = (
    pl_df.filter(pl.col('item_id') == 'A')
    .with_columns(netsales=pl.lit(120))
)

print(
    pl_df.update(sub_df, on='row_nr').collect()
)
# shape: (6, 6)
# ┌────────┬─────────┬──────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────┐
# │ row_nr ┆ item_id ┆ store_id ┆ sold_quantity ┆ total_sku_count ┆ netsales │
# │ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---           ┆ ---             ┆ ---      │
# │ u32    ┆ str     ┆ i64      ┆ i64           ┆ i64             ┆ i64      │
# ╞════════╪═════════╪══════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╪══════════╡
# │ 0      ┆ A       ┆ 2        ┆ 4             ┆ 0               ┆ 120      │
# │ 1      ┆ A       ┆ 2        ┆ 4             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# │ 2      ┆ A       ┆ 1        ┆ 1             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# │ 3      ┆ B       ┆ 1        ┆ 4             ┆ 0               ┆ 50       │
# │ 4      ┆ B       ┆ 2        ┆ 1             ┆ 1               ┆ 100      │
# │ 5      ┆ A       ┆ 1        ┆ 3             ┆ 1               ┆ 120      │
# └────────┴─────────┴──────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [when/then/otherwise](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html):

```py
df.with_columns(
    net_sales=pl.when(pl.col("item_id") == "A")
        .then(120)
        .otherwise(pl.col("net_sales"))
)
```

Comment: FYI, in `with_columns`, `then` and `otherwise`, if it encounters a string, the default is to treat it as a column name. That's relevant because you could just write `otherwise("netsales")` AND if, instead of `.then(120)`, you wanted `.then("one hundred twenty")` it wouldn't work as it'd look for a column named "one hundred twenty". Instead you'd need `.then(pl.lit("one hundred twenty"))`.